# Meteor, mongodb - canteen optimization

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, optimization, aldeed-tabular

**TL;DR:**
I'm making an app for a canteen. I have a collection with the persons and a collection where I "log" every meat took. I need to know those who DIDN'T take the meal.

**Long version:**

I'm making an application for my local Red Cross.

I'm trying to optimize this situation:

- there is a canteen at wich the helped people can take food at breakfast, lunch and supper. We need to know how many took the meal (and this is easy).
- if they are present they HAVE TO take the meal and eat, so we need to know how many (and who) HAVEN'T eat (this is the part that I need to optimize).
- When they take the meal the "cashier" insert their barcode, the program log the "transaction" in the log collection.

Actually, on creation of the template "canteen" I create a local collection "meals" and populate it with the data of all the people in the DB, (so ID, name, fasting/satiated), then I use this collection for my counters and to display who took the meal and who didn't.
(the variable "mealKind" is = "breakfast" OR "lunch" OR "dinner" depending on the actual serving.)

```
Template.canteen.created = function(){
  Meals=new Mongo.Collection(null);
  var today= new Date();today.setHours(0,0,1);
  var pers=Persons.find({"status":"present"},{fields:{"Name":1,"Surname":1,"barcode":1}}).fetch();
  pers.forEach(function(uno){
    var vediamo=Log.findOne({"dest":uno.codice,"what":mealKind, "when":{"$gte": today}});
    if(typeof vediamo=="object"){
      uno['eat']="satiated";
    }else{
      uno['eat']="fasting";
    }
    Meals.insert(uno);
  });
};

Template.canteen.destroyed = function(){
   meals.remove({});
};
```

From the meal collection I estrapolate the two colums of people satiated (with name, surname and barcode) and fasting, and I also use two helpers:

```
  fasting:function(){
    return Meals.find({"eat":"fasting"});
  }
  "countFasting":function(){
    return Meals.find({"eat":"fasting"}).count();
  }
//same for satiated
```

This was ok, but now the number of people is really increasing (we are arount 1000 and counting) and the creation of the page is very very slow, and usually it stops with errors so I can read that "100 fasting, 400 satiated" but I have around 1000 persons in the DB.

I can't figure out how to optimize the workflow, every other method that I tried involved (in a manner or another) more queries to the DB; I think that I missed the point and now I cannot see it.
I'm not sure about aggregation at this level and inside meteor, because of minimongo.

Although making this server side and not client side is clever, the problem here is HOW discriminate "fasting" vs "satiated" without cycling all the person collection.

**+1 if the solution is compatibile with aleed:tabular**

Comment: Looks like you rely entirely on client-side minimongo DB for your `Meals` tracking? What happens if your browser crashes / is accidentally closed?

Comment: Yep, I rely entirely on this. If the browser crashes when they re-enter the app the onCreated event fires and recreate the local-collection.
A server backed collection is more difficult to mantain because everyday I have to clear it...

Comment: Sorry, misintepreted the question, when the cashier insert the transaction I insert a document inside the Log collection of course.
So I have a long term track of the meals.
If the browser crashes it can recover without losing any data.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I am still not sure about what is causing your performance issue (too many things in client memory / minimongo, too many calls to it?), but you could at least try different approaches, more traditionally based on your server.

By the way, you did not mention either how you display your data or how you get the incorrect reading for your number of already served / missing `Persons`?

If you are building a classic HTML `table`, please note that browsers struggle rendering more than a few hundred rows. If you are in that case, you could implement a client-side table pagination / infinite scrolling. Look for example at jQuery [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) plugin (on which is based `aldeed:tabular`). Skip the step of building an actual HTML `table`, and fill it directly using [`$table.rows.add(myArrayOfData).draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()) to avoid the browser limitation.

---

**Original answer**

I do not exactly understand why you need to duplicate your `Persons` collection into a client-side `Meals` local collection?

This requires that you have first *all* documents of `Persons` sent from server to client (this may not be problematic if your server is well connected / local. You may also still have `autopublish` package on, so you would have already seen that penalty), and then cloning all documents (checking for your `Logs` collection to retrieve any previous passages), effectively doubling your memory need.

Is your server and/or remote DB that slow to justify your need to do everything locally (client side)?

Could be much more problematic, should you have more than one "cashier" / client browser open, their `Meals` local collections will not be synchronized.

If your server-client connection is good, there is no reason to do everything client side. Meteor will automatically cache just what is needed, and provide optimistic DB modification to keep your user experience fast (should you structure your code correctly).

- With [`aldeed:tabular`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular) package, you can easily display your `Persons` big table by "pages".
- You can also link it with your `Logs` collection using the [`dburles:collection-helpers`](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers) (IIRC there is an example en the `aldeed:tabular` home page).

Comment: Your explanation is very detailed, but probably I didn't explain the point very well. I make some work server side, but the server cannot afford over 900 queries every time someone opens the app.
The problem is to tell efficently who _didn't_ take the meal (I have all the others informations in only one query).

I'll check the collection-helpers documentation, thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe there is some misconception about how Meteor works, or I still do not understand your issue. In the code you shared, your app **already** makes 900 db queries when populating your `Meals` local collection, as it polls the `Log` collection for each `Persons` document. Now if you published your `Log` documents for the current date (or you have `autopublish` on), your client does not poll the server db, but its local cache (minimongo).

Comment: Yep, my code already make 900 query and I asked if there is a way (restructuring the code) to avoid or optimize this phase.  In fact i used client side exactly because in this way the queries are against minimongo and not against the server, but this is so slow also in this way (and IMHO making it server side can only make it slower, maybe I'm wrong).   My issue is that I wrote a bad piece of code and I need help to refocus about how to make the same task in a clever way.

Comment: Ansewring to your edit:
I wanted to use aldeed:tabular but with this setting is not possible.

Actually I'm just adding divs, to one bootstrap column, this is is not perfect (in fact I asked about suggestion to modify my code).

I get the wrong number because I use a counter (countFasting) that shows around 2-3 hundred person but there are at least 1500 registered.

I actually disabled the function but I'm still testing some variations because we need this numbers.

I think that the thing to do is reduce this problem from O(n) to O(1)